# double displaying very long number

Tags: java

I have a simple calculation that uses doubles but I'm getting an unexpected result and I can't understand why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class VersatileSnitSoft {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double amount;
        System.out.print("What’s the price of a CD-ROM? ");
        amount = myScanner.nextDouble();
        amount = amount + 25.00;
        System.out.print("We will bill $");
        System.out.print(amount); 
        System.out.println(" to your credit card.");

    }

}
```

If I enter 2.99 the result I get is..

```
We will bill $27.990000000000002 to your credit card.
```

Comment: You should not use floats or doubles for any calculation where you need absolute precision - any software dealing with financial transactions being a perfect example! I believe Java offers alternative numeric types to counter this - it might be worth reading into floating-point arithmetic too.

Comment: FYI. This is how 2.99 is represented in a double: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050046057057 The result is just an approximation; 2.99 can't be represented using given number of mantissa bits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot represent decimal values precisely whilst operating on doubles (or floats). 
Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

**Edit (2)**

Example here:

```
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("2.99");
amount = amount.add(new BigDecimal("25.00"));
System.out.println(amount.toString());
```

Ouput:

```
27.99
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however, I am fiarly new to Java and I don't understand why to use BigDecimal, it isn't a type I've seen before

Comment: You can fin additional references on item 48 of Effective Java. http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA219&ots=yYIoLft3N4&dq=effective%20java%20bigdecimal&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20bigdecimal&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Doubles (floating-point values in general) cannot always represent exactly what we think of intuitively as a precise value. This is because of the way in which floats are stored, and can vary from machine to machine and language to language. When you try to store `2.99`, the actual value that is stored may be very slightly different (e.g. `2.990000000000002`). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) gives a decent, quick overview of why.

You should therefore (as it says through the link) *never* use floating-point primitives to represent currency. Either use `BigDecimal`, or keep track of two integers yourself (e.g. `int dollars;` and `int cents;`).

Answer (score 1):

use DecimalFormat to display 2 digit after whole number

```
  DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
   String amt=f.format(amount);
   System.out.print("We will bill $");
    System.out.print(amt);
```

http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/21519

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has been asked a million times. You can find a good and quick description of it here [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

If you are just fooling around and you want it to print properly use

```
String prettyNumber = String.format("%.2f", doubleNumber);
```

Which is going to print 2 floating points. It will look correct, but it is only correct if precision (in the magnitude of 10^-16 or so) is not of interest to you.